# processingjs flickering when drawing more than one object

Tags: javascript, animation, processing, buffering, lag

In processingjs, I'm having trouble. The code I wrote works, but only for one circle. If there are two or more circles, they start to flicker (I'm guessing this is from a slow refresh rate from background()). Is there something I'm doing wrong in my code(posted below), or is that just the limit of processingjs's speed?

I'm sure there must be a way to acheive the same effect without the lag. I've seen more done in processing with less lag.

in addition, when two circles overlap they also start flickering (about twice as much). is there any way to fix that?

my code:

```
    int count;
    int[] circles;
    int numCircles;
    int color, color1, color2;
    void setup()
    {
    size($(document.body).width(),600);
    smooth();
    numCircles = 1;
    color = random(0,200);
    color1 = random(0, 200);
    color2 = random(0, 200);
    strokeWeight( 10 );

     frameRate( 60 );
```

```
count = 0;
circles = new int[numCircles*4];
for(int x = 0; x<circles.length; x+=4)
{
    circles[x]=random(0,width);
    circles[x+1]=random(0,height);
    if(random(0,1)==0)
    {
     circles[x+2] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
     circles[x+2] = -1;
    }
    if(random(0,1)==0)
    {
     circles[x+3] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
     circles[x+3] = -1;
    }

}


}



void draw()
{


background(255);
fill(255);
stroke(color, color1, color2);

ellipse(circles[count], circles[count+1], 500, 500);
if(abs(circles[count]-width)<=10)
{circles[count+2]=-abs(circles[count+2])}
if(abs(circles[count+1]-height)<=10)
{circles[count+3]=-abs(circles[count+3])}

if(circles[count]<=10)
{
 circles[count+2] = abs(circles[count+2]);
}
if(circles[count+1]<=10)
{
 circles[count+3] = abs(circles[count+3]);
}
circles[count]+=circles[count+2];
circles[count+1]+=circles[count+3];

count+=4;
if(count>circles.length-4)
{count = 0;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I was doing wrong

by looping through each circle in the draw function via a for loop I discovered I was able to update the location of each circle without having the delay between iterations of the draw() function which caused the flickering.